Kubernetes is no accepting traffic from my Load Balancer when I deploy it in Terraform in DigitalOcean
When I deploy my ingress controller I get an error from digital ocean dashboard
0/1
Kubernetes nodes accepting traffic

--
First I create my kubernetes cluster named avatares_cluster
# main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = "2.36.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "KEY"
}

resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "avatares_cluster" {
  name    = "avatars-cluster"
  region  = "nyc1"
  version = "1.29.1-do.0"

  node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    size       = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
    node_count = 1
  }
}

When the deployment finished I get the cluster_id and cluster name in order to introduce that data in the ingress file
terraform {
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source  = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = ">= 2.4.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.7.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.0.1"
    }
  }
}
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "KEY"
}
data "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "primary" {
  name = var.cluster_name
}


provider "kubernetes" {
  host             = data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.endpoint
  token            = data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.kube_config[0].token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.kube_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate
  )
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host  = data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.endpoint
    token = data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.kube_config[0].token
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
      data.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.primary.kube_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate
    )
  }
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress-nginx"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace  = "ingress-nginx"

  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/do-loadbalancer-name"
    value = format("%s-nginx-ingress", var.cluster_name)
  }
  depends_on = [ kubernetes_namespace.ingress ]
}

The load balancer is deployed well in Digital Ocean but it doesn't accept incoming traffic from kubernetes. What I'm doing wrong?
I'm trying to replicate this example from digital ocean github account:
https://github.com/digitalocean/terraform-provider-digitalocean/blob/main/examples/kubernetes/kubernetes-config/main.tf
